# Arduino C++ library syntax

Tags: library

I am looking at modifying the H3LI331DL I2C library posted by Seed Studio for communicating with the H3LI331DL accelerometer. The library hardcodes the address for the accelerometer in the header file. My end goal is to make the library require a slave address input argument so I can talk to 2 accelerometers on the same I2C bus. The chip has a pin that sets the LSB of its address.

Now onto the question. The library's .h file has the following statement:

`#define H3LIS331DL_MEMS_I2C_ADDRESS     0x18//0x32`

Is the 0x32 simply commented out or am I missing something here?

Thanks,

Emach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed commented out. SeeedStudio is a great company but their code (including code prettifying) is pretty sloppy, and sometimes a little dumbfounding.